# AWS Lambda fan in strategy

Tags: aws-lambda

I have a python script running locally that invokes a controller lambda asynchronously which in turn invokes worker lambdas asynchronously. Each worker writes a new file to S3 bucket. The local script keeps checking the number of files in the bucket and when number of workers = number of files, assumes that all work is done. This works but I am not happy about the “reduce” part of this strategy. What is a better way of achieving this? Can SNS/SQS play a role here? How would the local script be notified after the work is complete?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would look into AWS Step Functions to orchestrate your Lambda functions and perform a task when they are all done.

Comment: Are AWS Step functions part of the free tier? I had heard otherwise and hence did not pursue further.

Comment: "The Step Functions free tier includes 4,000 free state transitions per month." https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/pricing/

Comment: What happens in your local script when the number of workers = number of files ? i.e why do you need a notification to your local script?

Comment: When the work is done, local script reads all the files in S3 bucket and aggregates the results, plots the numbers produced by workers.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using AWS Step and feeding the job list into a `Map` step. This will run all operations concurrently (with a maximum concurrency of 40) and will not advance to the next phase of the Step function until all operations have completed.